# Error al ingresar datos de un $_GET

Tags: php, sql

Estoy ingresando datos a una base de datos con PHP, estuve buscando el error por un buen rato y al fin lo encontré... quisiera saber porque este código funciona:

```php
$command="INSERT INTO `productDevelopment` VALUES (NULL,1,{$_GET["dR_id"]},2,{$_SESSION["control"]["id_user"]},'".$_GET["n_dllo"]."',NULL,{$_GET["dosificacion"]},CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,NULL,'$formula[1]')";
```

Pero este NO funciona:

```php
$command="INSERT INTO `productDevelopment` VALUES (NULL,1,{$_GET["dR_id"]},2,{$_SESSION["control"]["id_user"]},{$_GET["n_dllo"]},NULL,{$_GET["dosificacion"]},CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,NULL,'$formula[1]')";
```

la única diferencia entre el primer código y el segundo es la forma en la que escribo este campo:

```
(funciona)
    ".$_GET['n_dllo']."
(no funciona)
    {$_GET['n_dllo']}
```

Pero la escritura con **`{ }`** me funciona en los demás campos.

Espero me ayuden a entender, feliz tarde.

Comment: +1 por haber el trabajo de investigación.

Comment: es probable que el campo `$_GET["n_dllo"]` sea string y al enviarlo sin las comillas causa error

Comment: Muéstranos lo que arroja un `var_dump($_GET);` Si hago una prueba con un `$_GET` simulado el código no da ningún error. Muéstranos también qué error te da a ti y dinos qué entiendes tú por *funciona* o *no funciona* en este contexto.

Answer (score 0):

he seguido las recomendaciones de [Kevin Delva](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/69657/kevin-delva) en sus comentarios y el problema era un error de sintaxis, debí de escribir esto:

```
'{$_GET['n_dllo']}'
```

Cuando insertamos un valor de tipo string o float debemos colocarlo entre comillas.